# Power BI - Working Days in a Month

Tags: powerbi, dax

Currently I can use the DAY function as shown below to assign a number to rach day of the month.

Column = (day('Dash Sales'[Date]))

How can I filter so that it only counts workdays?

Here are two tables to demonstrate what I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: You should add a column `Work day` to your `Date` table in Power BI, like explained [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DATEDIFF-Working-Days/td-p/130662)

Comment: Hi, I edited my post for further clarification.

Comment: OK, did you take a look at the link I provided? You can use `WEEKDAY`.

Comment: Hi, WEEKDAY returns a number 1 - 7.

Comment: The link NickyvV provided has exact answer to your question

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself clearly. I don't need a count as in there are x number of working days. If you look at the working days column in the link explanation, it simply shows a 1 or a 0 depending on the IF function. This would not help me.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the following code should give you your desired column.

```
WorkdayCount = IF(
    NOT(WEEKDAY('Dash Sales'[Date]) IN {1, 7}), 
    RANKX(
        FILTER(
            'Dash Sales', 
            'Dash Sales'[Date].[MonthNo] = EARLIER('Dash Sales'[Date].[MonthNo]) && 
            NOT(WEEKDAY('Dash Sales'[Date]) IN {1, 7}) 
            ),
        'Dash Sales'[Date].[Day],
        , ASC, Dense))
```

Results:
[image: Results]